# Limit the crawl to subpages of the seed url

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I have this set, which crawls pages based on the  seed

---

> {
>         "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.host.HostURLFilter",
>         "name": "HostURLFilter",
>         "params": {
>           "ignoreOutsideHost": false,
>           "ignoreOutsideDomain": true
>         }
>       }

---

but, how can I limit to just subpages of the seed. 
For eg. If I have a seed as "https://www.test.com/", with the above settings, the crawler also crawls and adds urls like "https://stg.test.com/" and its subpages etc.

How can I limit the crawl, to "https://www.test.com/" and just subpages of this seed, like "https://www.test.com/test1", "https://www.test.com/test2" etc.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set *ignoreOutsideHost* to true in the config of the HostUrlFilter.

Comment: Thanks Julien. Is there a way to exclude a few urls patterns, like using regex etc. Say for example: crawl everything for the seed domain, but skip everything that has /exclude/ in the url.

Comment: See https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/filtering/regex/RegexURLFilter.java
The URLFilters are listed on https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/URLFilters